# Getting data from hidden html (popup) using BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the name of a link in a popup in wikipedia. So when you hover a link in wikipedia, it brings up a little snippet from the intro to that link. I need to scrape that information but I am unsure where it would be in the source. When I inspect the element(as it is popped up) this is the html (for this example I am hovering over the link "Greek")

```
<a dir="ltr" lang="en" class="mwe-popups-extract" href="/wiki/Ancient_Greek"> 
<p>The <b>Ancient Greek</b> language includes the forms of Greek...(a bunch more text)...</p></a>
```

What I need to extract is the href which = "/wiki/Ancient_Greek" but this piece of html disappears when I am not hovering the link. Is there a way (with BS4 and python) to extract this information with the source html I am scraping?

EDIT: I can't afford to make additional calls to webpages because the project takes long to run as it is. If there is anyway to change how I am retrieving the source such that I can get the popup information that would be helpful. This project is giant and getting this popup information is crucial.

any suggestions at all that don't require a complete rebuild of the project is extremely appreciated-- I am using urllib to pull source(with requests) and bs4 to scrape through.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post your code?

Comment: You cannot do this with urllib. You need a web driver that is capable of executing javascript (i.e. loading the popup) because the data simply does not exist on the client side till you load the popup. If you use splinter, you can [run it with the chrome web driver](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drivers/chrome.html) which will be very fast and will not actually open a web browser window.

Comment: @jstein123 for splinter, how does it compare to bs4. My entire platform uses bs4 for scraping. (Let it be known this platform has over 35,000 lines of code a simple switch isn't easy if it involves rebuilding)

Comment: You would use splinter like urllib (i.e. to actually scrape the data). Bs4 is used to extract information from the already scraped data, so you would still use bs4 once you get the data from the popup with splinter. The data returned from splinter will be raw html just like urllib.

Comment: Once you use splinter to hover over the popup to bring it up, you can simply do `browser.html` to get the html of the page, then use bs4 to find and extract the popup html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your question you say that you "...can't afford to make additional calls to webpages..." but that's what your browser is doing behind the scenes. The html for the page you are looking at doesn't contain the content that you require.

To demonstrate this:

1. In your browser, open a Wikipedia page such as [Greek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek).
2. Bring up the Developer Tools window (Ctrl+Shift+i in Chrome).
3. Click on the Network tab and make sure that the red button is lit so that all web requests are logged.
4. Hover over a link in the page such as [Ancient Greek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greek).

   You will see that the act of hovering over the link triggers a GET request to the [Ancient_Greek summary page](https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/Ancient_Greek).
5. Click on "Ancient_Greek" in the network tab log to show details of the request.
6. Click on the Response tab on the right.

   You should see the JSON response containing a field called "extract_html" containing the content you require: `"<p>The <b>Ancient Greek</b> language includes the forms...`

Therefore, in order to get the information you need, every time you encounter a link to `<a href="/wiki/something" /a>` you will have to make a GET request to `https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/something`

Comment: Wow this does the closest thing to no additions to code just some more querying of data.

Answer (score 5):

With popups and other data that only appears dynamically via javascript, you can't just scrape the data using something like urllib.

You could use a browser controller like [splinter](http://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) or [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) which will allow you to automatically hover over or click things to bring up the popup and then extract its data. After you get the popup html, you can use BS4 to clean it up.

Ex:

```
from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser()
browser.visit("http://google.com")
button = browser.find_by_name('button1')
button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Selenium for that

here is a simple demo on how to locate html text input by name:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="text" name="password">
</form>
```

and here is python code using selenium driver:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement; 
WebElement usernameElement = driver.findElement(By.name("username")); 
WebElement passwordElement = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
```